# How do i pass cookie value in multiple subdomain in sso mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

For Url `xyz.com`(for first web application project):
while log in the user i store the information in cookie here in Login page:

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                             1,
                             serializeModel.UserEmail,
                             DateTime.Now,
                             DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(55),
                             _rememberme,
                             userData);

                    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                    HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

Here is the Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            try
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

                CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
                newUser.UserID  = serializeModel.UserID;
                newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;
                newUser.LastName = serializeModel.LastName;
                newUser.ProfilePicture = serializeModel.ProfilePicture;
                newUser.UserCode = serializeModel.UserCode;
                newUser.UserEmail = serializeModel.UserEmail;
                newUser.UserType = serializeModel.UserType;
                newUser.Fk_Parent = serializeModel.Fk_Parent;
                newUser.CompanyID = serializeModel.CompanyID;
                newUser.isSASS = serializeModel.isSASS;
                newUser.Commission = serializeModel.Commission;
                newUser.CommissionManager = serializeModel.CommissionManager;
                newUser.ISACount = serializeModel.ISACount;

                HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = null;
            }
        }
    }

    interface ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        int UserID { get; set; }
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
        string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        Guid UserCode { get; set; }
        string UserEmail { get; set; }
        int UserType { get; set; }
        int Fk_Parent { get; set; }
        string CompanyID { get; set; }
        Nullable<bool> isSASS { get; set; }
        double? Commission { get; set; }
        double? CommissionManager { get; set; }
        Nullable<int> ISACount { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
    {
        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
        public bool IsInRole(string role) {
            string inRole = string.Empty;
            inRole =Enum.GetName(typeof(UserType), UserType);

            if (inRole == role)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        public CustomPrincipal(string email)
        {
            this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(email);
        }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        public Guid UserCode { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int UserType { get; set; }
        public int Fk_Parent { get; set; }
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isSASS { get; set; }
        public double? Commission { get; set; }
        public double? CommissionManager { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ISACount { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the sub domain of `a.xyz.com`(2nd web application project)(both project are in MVC5 c#.
Here is the Global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            try
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

                CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
                newUser.UserID = serializeModel.UserID;
                newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;
                newUser.LastName = serializeModel.LastName;
                newUser.ProfilePicture = serializeModel.ProfilePicture;
                newUser.UserCode = serializeModel.UserCode;
                newUser.UserEmail = serializeModel.UserEmail;
                newUser.UserType = serializeModel.UserType;
                newUser.Fk_Parent = serializeModel.Fk_Parent;
                newUser.CompanyID = serializeModel.CompanyID;
                newUser.isSASS = serializeModel.isSASS;
                newUser.Commission = serializeModel.Commission;
                newUser.CommissionManager = serializeModel.CommissionManager;
                newUser.ISACount = serializeModel.ISACount;

                HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = null;
            }
        }
    }

    interface ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        int UserID { get; set; }
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
        string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        Guid UserCode { get; set; }
        string UserEmail { get; set; }
        int UserType { get; set; }
        int Fk_Parent { get; set; }
        string CompanyID { get; set; }
        Nullable<bool> isSASS { get; set; }
        double? Commission { get; set; }
        double? CommissionManager { get; set; }
        Nullable<int> ISACount { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
    {
        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            string inRole = string.Empty;
            inRole = Enum.GetName(typeof(UserType), UserType);

            if (inRole == role)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        public CustomPrincipal(string email)
        {
            this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(email);
        }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        public Guid UserCode { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int UserType { get; set; }
        public int Fk_Parent { get; set; }
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isSASS { get; set; }
        public double? Commission { get; set; }
        public double? CommissionManager { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ISACount { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomPrincipalSerializeModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        public Guid UserCode { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public int UserType { get; set; }
        public int Fk_Parent { get; set; }
        public string CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> isSASS { get; set; }
        public double? Commission { get; set; }
        public double? CommissionManager { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ISACount { get; set; }
    }
```

But the issue is that in 2nd subdomain i am getting null value always.Here i am store the value and need to validate in 2nd sudomain.in 2nd subdomain global.asax i am getting null value in `authCookie` always.

So how do i resolved??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work, but you can try to configure your web.config on this way:

```
<forms name="CookieName" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="false" domain="xyz.com" />
```

Comment: is  machine key is  needed ??

Answer (score 0):

First, this will only work for subdomains. Cookies are domain-bound, but you can use a wildcard domain, so you could then share the cookie between domains like `a.xyz.com`, `b.xyz.com` and `xyz.com`. However, you could *never* share it with `otherdomain.com`.

Sharing the cookie will require two components:

1. Set the cookie domain to `.xyz.com`

   ```
   <forms ... domain=".xyz.com" />
   ```

   That only covers your auth cookie, though. For adding manual cookies, you'd need to similarly set the `.Domain` property of the cookie you're creating.
2. Generate a machine key and set the same machine key for each site. You can generate the machine key in IIS by going to the Features view of your server instance and double-clicking the "Machine Key" icon. Pick something for the validation and encryption method. I'd recommend avoiding both MD5 and SHA1, since both are extremely vulnerable ciphers. Then, click "Generate Keys" on the right sidebar. Add the following tag to the Web.config for every site, with those generated values:

   ```
   <machineKey validation="HMACSHA256" validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." />
   ```

   Obviously, you'd want to use the validation method you chose when generating the keys in place of "HMACSHA256", if that wasn't the one your chose.

Comment: is the machine key for .xyz.com and a.xyz.com are same??that means in both of the project is it needed same??

Comment: Yes. Every single site that needs access to the same cookie would need exactly the same machineKey tag.

Comment: only these two things can solved request.cookies formsauthentication.formscookiename is null??

Comment: Well, let's just say those are the pre-requisites. It definitely will not work without those two things, but that doesn't bar some other issue you might have.

Comment: What I've given you is the bare minimum. There may be a more comprehensive solution, but if it doesn't include those two pieces it will not work.

Comment: sir if i use <forms in web.config [Authorize(Roles = "Associate,AssocateManager")] not working in controller